# Genymotion: failed to attach drive

Tags: drive, genymotion

[image]

Did lot of search in google but still not solved...

using windows 7 basic 64...

firstly i was run perfectly but after i made some change in vmbox for file sharing after that its been stopped,i did undo but still getting error...re install,restart,remove all done but really tired to solve this so if u know proper way to solve this then please tell me how???

Comment: Nt a question for SO. Try [su]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too. U can change the VirtualBox path in the Gemony Setting.